# Is there any transformation for the polynomial $x^4+ax^3+bx+1$ to either one of these forms $x^4+cx+d$ or $x^4+cx^3+d$ ? (like brioschi quintic form)

Tags: polynomials, transformation, quartics

I  would like to transform the degree 4 polynomial to the degree 4 polynomial with specific powers of x removed. something like depressed cubic form or Brioschi quintic. Do we have any special transformation for quartic polynomials?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.